# What is a better way of handling import *

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have a class which looks like the following:

```
class TestClass():
    from somewhere import *

    def test_function(self):
        pass
```

Of course I am getting a syntax warning about import * only being allowed at the module level. All of the posts I have seen have been about why this is a bad idea, and not actually offering a way to handle this better. We are looking at moving to Python 3 and need to take care of this as one of our obstacles before moving over.

So what would be a better way to handle this? Would putting the import statements into the `__init__.py` be the way to handle this? If so, what would that look like?

Comment: How many objects are being imported from `somewhere`? The "right" way to do it would be to just explicitly list the objects from `somewhere` you need to import, or just `import somewhere` and use `somewhere.object` instead of `object`.

Comment: Why do you want to do `from somewhere import *` rather than `import somewhere`? The latter does not pollute the namespace and should generally be preferred to the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add all the elements from `somewhere` as elements of your class, you could use a loop and a combination of [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
import somewhere

class TestClass():
    def test_function(self):
        pass

for name in getattr(somewhere, '__all__', 
                    (n for n in dir(somewhere) if not n.startswith('_'))):
    setattr(TestClass, name, getattr(somewhere, name))
```

This'll add the exact same names from `somewhere` to `TestClass` as the `from somewhere import *` statement would; either all names listed in the `__all__` sequence, if set, otherwise all names that do not start with an underscore.

Rather than import individual attributes (functions, etc.), you should really create a base class in `somewhere` instead:

```
class BaseSomewhere:
    somewhere_thing1 = 'something'

    def somewhere_thing2(self):
        # do something
```

then import *that*:

```
import somewhere

class TestClass(somewhere.BaseSomewhere):
    def test_function(self):
        pass
```

Comment: But a better design pattern would be to create a `somewhere.DummyClass` that has all those methods explicitly defined, then do `class TestClass(somewhere.DummyClass)`

Comment: @AdamSmith: Absolutely agree; I'll write that up too.

Answer (score 3):

The better way is to just `import something` and then use `something.function_you_want_to_call` rather than `function_you_want_to_call`

Comment: I agree that this is the better way, what happens when you have possibly thousands of functions you want to call?